# How do can I get the BackHandler to work?

Tags: react-native

I'm following the instructions for installing the BackHandler:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler

The componentDidMount call is being made and the handler is getting installed. I removed the goBack in the handler example because I want the Menu button to do nothing for now just to test it.

The Menu button always exits the app now matter what. I've install the handler in the top level component as well as the component that has focus  and it makes no difference. Menu always exits app.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, what navigation library are you using? the event `hardwareBackPress` is for android hardware back button not for the Menu Button as you said. If you are trying to do something with Menu button try research more, it could be hard since Menu button is hard binding with android system event :D good luck

Comment: Not according to this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler "tvOS: Detect presses of the menu button on the TV remote. "